# How do I open another activity from using androids 'Navigation Drawer'

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am creating a new project with Eclipse's 'Navigation Drawer' template. I see no documentation or tutorials as far as how I would go about changing each item in the drawer's Listview to go to a new activity once clicked, rather then reuse the same one and change the top title text. Only tutorials I'm seeing is how to implement this Navigation Drawer, which looks like is useless now that Eclipse allows you to make a project with it. How would I make it so I can click on each item and have it go to a new activity?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you claim you have looked at the Google tutorials on how to use a `NavigationDrawer`, it seems like you did absolutely no research whatsoever.

When reading the tutorial, you will come across this paragraph: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ListItemClicks

It describes how to react to click events on the drawer.

The basic idea is that you creat a click-listener for callbacks when clicking the drawer. Inside the callback method, you start your desired `Activity`.

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         // start your activity here, depending on click position
    }
}
```

In the main-Activity, set the click-listener:

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```